# Collecting data from a single SQLite column

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Still getting the hang of all this.

My question is this - I have a single column that I wish to collect scores from in a database under a single table:

```
23
45
84
56
```

I want to collect them all and add together.

I've tried this:

```
String[] projection2 = {BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_CREDIT_SCORE };
Cursor databaseCursor2 = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection2,
        null, null, null);
int number = 0;
if (databaseCursor2 != null) {
    while (databaseCursor2.isAfterLast() == false) {
        databaseCursor2.moveToFirst();
        number = number + databaseCursor2.getInt(databaseCursor2
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_CREDIT_SCORE));
    }
}
```

But it just crashes the app. Why is this happening?

Comment: what does the crash say on logcat? point to the line numbers affected too.

Comment: It doesn't actually crash, I think it just goes into an endless loop, the screen goes black until the android system comes up and says it isn't responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an endless loop here:

```
while (databaseCursor2.isAfterLast() == false){
    databaseCursor2.moveToFirst();
    ...
}
```

You never move to the next row in the cursor. Normally I use something like this instead:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // do cursor stuff
    ....
}
```